# Nomenclature: Why template “non-type parameter” and not “value parameter”?

Tags: c++, templates

Why are non-type template parameters called “non-type” and not “value” parameters? It feels even wrong to me calling them that (e.g. in teaching) because templates as parameters to templates aren’t types, but “non-type” does not include them. Template template parameters weren’t even a later addition to the standard.

---

Edit: In the comments, there is talk about a dichotomy. Maybe my point isn’t clear enough. There’s *three* kinds of template parameters:

- Types (e.g. `T` in `template<typename T>`)
- Non-type (e.g. `x` in `template<auto x>`)
- Templates (e.g. `C` in `template<template<typename> C>`)

One of them is named as “non-[one of the others]” and I wondered where this arguably wrong pattern comes from. You can argue about “*value* parameter” all day, but that’s not what my question really is about.

Comment: Seems opinion based.  Also, `non-type` seems more accurate to me. Even more, `value parameter` sounds wrong to me. You can call it whatever you like as long as the meaning is clear to you. There are three terms `type`, `non-type` and `template template` for template parameters.

Comment: colloquially "value" is more general. `T = int` -> "the value of `T` is `int`". `T = 42` -> "the value of `T` is `42`"

Comment: Not sure why there's a "subjective" close vote. This is early C++, see "Design & Evolution of C++" for the published rationale.

Comment: It gets at the dichotomy of a parameter that's a type, a "type parameter", and a parameter that's not a type, a "non-type parameter". If the terms were "type parameter" and "value parameter" that would suggest that there can be some other kind of parameter as well.

Comment: @PeteBecker What dichotomy? There is literally three kinds: value, type, and template.

Comment: @JasonLiam, My question is about why/how the pattern of “A”, “non-A”, and “C“ came to be and that there are reasonable “B”s. It’s not about a specific “B”. When writing the question, that seemed absolutely obvious to me, but apparently it was not.

Comment: @Bolpat Because `value` is like a synonym for `argument`. So using `value parameter` sounds like `argument parameter` which is very confusing. The same is explained in my answer below. On the other hand, `non-type` is very clear about the fact that the entity we're dealing with is "not a type". Now, that entity can be "argument" in which case the term becomes *"non-type argument"* and that entity can also be "parameter" in which case the term becomes *"non-type parameter"*.

Comment: @MSalters, so it’s just legacy.

Comment: @Bolpat: An authoritative answer to this could only be provided by members of the committee at the time C++98 was being drafted. I suspect that template parameters that weren't types were added fairly late and weren't given a whole lot of thought, but that's just a suspicion. Only the people who were there could know more.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I just grabbed the Annotated Reference Manual (1990), which was written directly after the C++ Committee (back then ANSI X3J16) accepted Bjarne's 1988 Usenix proposal. That 1988 proposal already had the non-type parameters. IOW, there's never been a `template`  without them.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly because the term **value** is often associated with the term **argument** as opposed to the term **parameter**.

For example, a template *type-parameter* named `T` can take a template *type-argument* like `int`, `double` etc. Another way of saying this is a template *type-parameter* `T` can be passed a value like `int`, `double` etc.

Similarly, for an ordinary nontemplate function like `void f(int t)`, the parameter `t` can be passed an argument like `5`, `6` etc. Another way of saying this is that the parameter `t` can be passed a value like `5`, `6` etc.

---

The point is that `value` is a more general term and is typically associated with **argument** and not **parameter**. So, the term `non-type` is more specific as it usually indicates only parameter while the term `value` often indicates passed argument. Note that you can add a qualifier like *"argument"* or *"parameter"* with the term `non-type` to get terms like *"non-type argument"* and *"non-type parameter"* respectively.

On the other hand if we were to use the term `value`(instead of `non-type`), then we will get terms like *"value parameter"* and *"value argument"* which for the former(`value parameter`) sounds odd to me because `value` is usually associated with `argument`.

---

Basically, `value` is like a synonym for `argument`. So using the term *"value parameter"* sounds like *"argument parameter"* which is very confusing. On the other hand, *non-type* is very clear about the fact that the entity we're dealing with is *"not a type"*. Now, that entity can be "argument" in which case the term becomes "non-type argument" and that entity can also be "parameter" in which case the term becomes "non-type parameter".